# Why can't I bind the control key and plus key to a Tkinter text widget in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically I wanted to bind two keys to a text widget those keys are the control key and the plus key.

This is what I tried:

```
Textbox1.bind("<Control-plus>", DoSomething)
```

This for whatever reason doesn't work.

It doesn't go to my function and it doesn't return any errors if you were wondering.

But for some other reason this works:

```
Textbox1.bind("<Control-minus>", DoSomething)
```

Why is this?

And how can I bind the control key and plus key?

Comment: Your code works fine for me on OSX. Can you provide a complete [mcve]? Also, what platform are you running on?

Comment: normally to get `+` you have to use `Shift+=` and maybe this makes problem.

Comment: on Linux I have to press `Ctrl+Shift+=` to run code assigned to `<Control-plus>` - `Ctrl+=` works with `<Control-equal>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what system you use but on Linux normally to display `+` you have to use `Shift =` - and this can make problem.

`<Control-plus>` means `Ctrl Shift =`

`<Control-equal>` means `Ctrl =`  (which can means `Ctrl +` for you)